# Java Total Books Calculation

Tags: java

Please help, I am trying to calculate the total number of books, based on the quantities read from an input file. I have tried to calculate the total number of books, but right now my code is just producing the last quantity it reads from the file as the total for totalBooks. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but any guidance would be much appreciated.

Here is what I have...

Note: The part of my program that I am trying to fix is under the comment  //Calculate Total Books

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BookstoreInventory
{
public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException
{
//Vaiable declartions
int edition, quanity;
double pricePerBook;
String isbn, author, title, publisherCode;

//Open the file and set delimiters
File file = new File("inventory.txt");
Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(file);
inputFile.useDelimiter("_|/|\\r?\\n");

//read from the file
while (inputFile.hasNext())
{
  isbn = inputFile.next();
    System.out.println(formatISBN(isbn)); //Need to move at end
  author = inputFile.next();
    System.out.println(getLastName(author));  //need to remove at end
  title = inputFile.next();
    System.out.println(truncateTitle(title));  //need to remove at end
  edition = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println(edition(edition));   //need to remove at end
  publisherCode = inputFile.next();
    System.out.println(publisher(publisherCode));   //need to remove at end
  quanity = inputFile.nextInt();
    System.out.println(quanity);     //need to remove at end
  pricePerBook = inputFile.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("$" + pricePerBook);   //need to remove at end

  //Calculate Total Books
  int totalBooks = 0;
  totalBooks += quanity;
  System.out.println("Total books: " + totalBooks);
}

//Close the flie
inputFile.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `quantity+= inputFile.nextInt();`

You have to calculate total quantity so you need to update your previous quantity by adding next quantity, instead of replacing